# -webkit-transition not working on google chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I've been working on a site and I've encountered a problem with transitions which only only happens in Chrome. Somehow Chrome doesn't want to do the transition which every other browser I use ( Safari, Firefox ) does.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="kategoria_box">
    <div class="kategoria_box_header">
        <h4>Fürdő</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="kategoria_box_image">
        <a href="termekek/kategoriak/furdo/">
            <img src="http://mondano.hu/img/furdo.jpg">
            <span class="caption">
                <p>Fürdőszoba</p>
            </span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here's the CSS:

```
div.kategoria_box_image {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight: 200;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

div.kategoria_box_image img {
    left: 0;
    max-width: 460px;
    -webkit-transition: all 600ms ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 600ms ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 600ms ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all 600ms ease-out;
    transition: all 600ms ease-out;
}

div.kategoria_box_image .caption {
    opacity: 0;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 60px 0 0px 0px;
    background-color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    color: #5d5d5d;
    z-index: 100;
    -webkit-transition: all 600ms ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 600ms ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 600ms ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all 600ms ease-out;
    transition: all 600ms ease-out;
    left: 0;
}

div.kategoria_box_image:hover .caption {
    opacity: 0.82;
}
```

Is something wrong about my code apart from being coded in my own unique style ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the webkit- prefix anymore. You forgot to set top:0 for span.caption

http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions

Here's my codepen:
http://codepen.io/dschu/pen/XbwYom

```
div.kategoria_box_image {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight: 200;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

div.kategoria_box_image img {
    left: 0;
    max-width: 460px;
    transition: all 600ms ease-out;
}

div.kategoria_box_image .caption {
    opacity: 0;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 60px 0 0px 0px;
    background-color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    color: #5d5d5d;
    z-index: 100;
    transition: all 600ms ease-out;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

div.kategoria_box_image:hover .caption {
    opacity: 0.82;
}
```